# Integer type for row keys in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm using only integer keys in column family and it pointless to convert them to string every time.

So, how can I make them integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 0.6 you can't. Row keys are always strings.

In 0.7 row keys are binary so you can use a 32 or 64 bit int if that makes more sense.